# How to store versioned data in an InfluxDB measurement?

Tags: influxdb

I would like to use InfluxDB to store forecast data. Each forecast has an emission date, a target date, and a value. I receive several forecasts with different emission dates for the same target date.

I would like to be able to retrieve

1. the latest forecast (the one with the latest emission date) for each target date,
2. all the forecasts that have a certain emission date.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you will be looking at having your forecast's `emission_dates` to be stored as part of the `time` field, then the `target_dates` as a tag and lastly storing your `value` in the value field.

**Example:**

```
name: forecast
time                target_dates        value
----                ------------        -----
1546516616386036270 1546000000000000000 500
1546516616390715128 1547000000000000000 600
1546516616734277026 1548000000000000000 700
```

The reason why I choice `target_dates` as tag is because tags are indexed. In case you are not aware of indexing you can find out more [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/key_concepts/).

See under "Why indexing matters: The schema case study"

This scheme design meets your requirement because;

1. To get the latest forecast based on the emission date, you can do a `SELECT * from forecast order by DESC limit 1`
2. To get all forecast of a certain emission date. Simply do `SELECT * FROM "forecast" WHERE "target_dates" = '1547000000000000000'`

Something worth noting here is that the `target_dates` above is on `epoch` time, format, you should be able to store any string datetime format you want.

Comment: Thank you! However, I might not have formulated the question correctly: `SELECT * from forecast order by DESC limit 1` returns a single value. The goal was to have one value (the latest forecast) **per target date**.

Comment: You are right.`GROUP BY target_dates` is what you need.